# SQL Server connection string for MVC 5 app

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

I'm new to SQL Server, so I don't know most of the concepts that are into it.

Basically I deployed my app to a windows server creating a **IIS Pool** with a **new non-admin user**, for the sake of this, let's say the user is `MyWinUser`, and the pool is `MyIISPool`.

Now, when it comes to SQL Server full edition, [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx) suggest to use a connection string like the following for the **default server instance**

```
Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=False;User Id=userid;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

And this one for an **specific instance**

```
Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

That being said, I don't know what an sql server instance is (yes I checked [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/11746/what-is-a-sql-server-instance) but I still don't understand).

Moreover, I tried the first connection string passing `MyWinUser` for the **User Id** and it's password for the password, but it says it couldn't log in.

I also tried the second string using `Data Source=ServerName\MyWinUser` but it didn't work.

Just in case, I logged to SQL Server Management checked inside the `Security` folder inside my database (let's call it `MyDB`), in the subfolder `Users` there is `MyWinUser` so I'm guessing `MyWinUser` does have permission to at least connect to that database.

What am I missing, what should I do, does it even works like this?

PS: If possible, I'd like to connect to said DB using the windows account `MyWinUser`.

Comment: The first connection string won't work with a Windows account. You can use a Windows account for SQL Server authentication, and vice versa. So if you want to use a Windows account, the Integrated Security should be true and the website should be running as that Windows account (and the account should have the necessary permissions).

Comment: so basically, the second string is the way to go?

Comment: I believe so, but I'm not intimately familiar with SQL Server. Check [this site](http://www.connectionstrings.com/). I think you'll find it valuable.

Answer (score 0):

If the application pool for your site is running under MyWinUser, and this is the account you want to connect to the database with, you can write your connection string like this:

```
Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Otherwise, you might need to include the Windows domain with the username.

```
Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=False;User Id=YourDomainName\MyWinUser;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```